# IIS 7.5 App pool setting "Virtual Memory Limit (KB)" seems to take effect at a different level

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, application-pools

I'm diagnosing problems with / trying to control a website which has a memory leak. The IIS setting "Virtual Memory Limit (KB)" has been set to 15728640 (15GB!) but the App pool seems to be recycling when the w3wp process is at a level somewhere closer to 500MB which is too low for this site because it is memory intensive.

I have set that limit to 0 to see if it is the cause of the recycling and it does seem to be. The w3wp process is now growing again. Why would this limit be so inaccurate? Does 15728640 exceed the maximum you can set this to?

Comment: According to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/167851/how-to-limit-the-memory-used-by-an-application-in-iis?answertab=active#tab-top) answer > If you are on a 64bit platform, you should be aware that ASP.NET app's aggressively reserve virtual memory. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671075/memory-usage-of-each-application-pool?answertab=active#tab-top) you can see how to check the used private and virtual bytes.